# How to refresh keyboard/returnKey while editing textField in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to make my app change the returnKeyType from Next to Go, when all my textfields contain text.
Everywhere I've been looking, people talks about textField.reloadInputViews() - but also they talk about that this method doesnt work anymore, after iOS8.. So whats the alternative? I've tried to make an observer, checking if the textfields contains stuff, and that seems to work properly - but my returnKey doesn't change, before i change textField - I need it to change "real time", as soon as theres text in all my fields.

Can anyone help me with a solution please? :-)

Best regards!

Answer (score 5):

Fixed it with

```
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

thanks anyway :p